# Implement queue rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, queue, delayed-job, resque

That's my issue.

I'm implementing a system where a video has to wait his own turn to access to such resource and being processed. So i need to implement a queue that receives a signal when the resource is free so that the rest of requests could be satisfied. It is supposed that not more of 10/20 requests would be in queue. The resource use depends on the length of the video.

I read something about resque ad delay_job. What do you thing is better for my needs?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Both DJ and Resque are gems to help the background jobs. Main dereference is DJ stores jobs in DB but Resque in Redis.

**I supports Resque** , because

```
 1. A Ruby library for creating, querying, and processing jobs 

 2. A Rake task for starting a worker which processes jobs

 3. A Sinatra app for monitoring queues, jobs, and workers.
```

Simple to integrate with Rails application.

Answer (score 0):

If you need something simple that only runs on one machine I would suggest you use delayed_job. 
I've had much success with using it to transcode videos on the server and setup and administration is pretty trivial.

See the documentation on [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) for instructions on how to set it up.